# Script to set linked tables doesn't save username and password

Tags: ms-access, vbscript, odbc, ms-access-2010

I recently developed a simple Access 2010 database for a client. It was designed without VBA, just using macros so it wouldn't trigger any security warnings. The only problem was that it uses ODBC linked tables connected to a SQL Server Express database, and I needed a way to reset the tables' connection strings once installed on my client's computer.

I developed a simple VBscript that goes through the linked tables, copies their names into a dictionary, and then recreates the tables with a new data source:

```
For Each key In tcmw.Keys
    Set td = db.CreateTableDef(key)
    td.Connect = "ODBC;Description=xxx;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=xxx\SQLEXPRESS;DATABASE=TCM;User=xxx;Password=xxx;"
    td.SourceTableName = key
    db.TableDefs.Append td
Next
```

The script seems to work, but when I hover over the linked tables, I see the following data source. It has `Trusted_Connection=Yes` instead of the specified username and password:

```
ODBC;Description=xxx;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=xxx\SQLEXPRESS;Trusted_Connection=Yes
```

That's not what I set the data source to, and I'm not sure why that would be happening. Is there a step I'm missing to get the username and password saved in the linked table definitions?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know positively but I don't think Access saves the credentials in the connection information. I'm using SQL Server 2008 with an Access 2010 front-end and here's the connection information I see when I hover:

```
ODBC;Driver=SQL Server Native Client 10.0;SERVER=localhost\SSE2008;APP=Microsoft Office 2010;Database=MyDatabaseName;;TABLE=dbo.SQLTableName
```

This maybe wouldn't work well for really large projects but I actually run code when the user opens the front end that deletes all of the SQL Server linked tables and recreates them using information that I store in a local table. I'm very happy with how it works but this project only has 22 tables.

I see you mentioned that you use only macros and no VBA in your project. I'm skeptical that you'll be able to make your project work reliably without using some code, at least to handle your linked tables. The way I remember I went the route I did because I had a lot of frustration making linked tables maintain their connection information. In my case I wasn't using Trusted Connections (or Windows authentication). Instead I was using SQL Server authentication which seems to be less resilient when it comes to maintaining connection information without user intervention.

Comment: Thanks. If this turns out to be the case, resetting the connection information would be an option for me, since there are only 5 tables to work with. I also use a VBscript to download and launch the database, so I could do that from there. I'll definitely prepare for that. I don't usually develop without code, but I was foolish enough to give my client the option this time, not really thinking she'd go for it. :-\